# Error :No dex file created at in android studio

Tags: dex

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No dex files created at C:\Users\comp\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\instant-run_f4d43731f9d6584756f1a09b2bf7c50227778da0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Disabling Instant Run solved it for me.In Android Studio.

Prefrences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and disable Instant Run by unchecking the box.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Disabling Instant Run solved it for me.

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and disable Instant Run by unchecking the box.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Gradle scripts->build gradle(module app)
add multiDexEnabled in default configure
default configure{
multiDexEnabled}